# Why does Azure Function slow down when process multiple messages

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have develop Azure Function App which read csv file and convert to list of object. The Azure Function App is queue trigger (azure storage queue). When I test on local I drop messages at the same time the result show as below

1. 1 message   Duration = 9600 ms. for each execution
2. 3 messages  Duration = 19000 ms. for each execution
3. 5 messages  Duration = 42600 ms. for each execution

My question is why the function is slower when process multiple messages at the same time?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential reasons why an Azure Function may slow down when processing multiple messages:
For Example, due to
1.**Concurrency Limits**
2.**Throttling**
3.**Large Data Processing**
4.**Service Plan** …etc
Follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices?tabs=csharp) to create more reliable functions.

**Example**
I created a queue function app and I am able to send message without delay.

**Sent Message from Queue:**
[image]

**Received in Function:**
[image]

**More Sample Messages from queue to

function**
[image]